# "@Model", "@Viewbag" and "@Url" "does not exist in the current context" Razor MVC3 when using Visual Studio 11 Beta/Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've created an MVC3 application in Visual Studio 10.  When editing views the "@Model", "@Viewbag" and "@Url" all appear valid.

I recently installed Visual Studio 11 Beta and when editing (or creating) views I get "x does not exist in current context" error for the above keywords and obviously no intelli-sense.

I have since installed Visual Studio 2012 RC hoping it was just a Visual Studio 11 Beta issue.... it wasn't.
Since running it in Visual Studio 2012 RC I've noticed the "@Html" key word exists however however the the intelli-sense list is limited - anything relating to the Model (eg "@Html.EditorFor()") and anything in the "Render" family is missing.

If I run the project everything is fine.

Now if I create a new project within Visual Studio 11 Beta/2012 RC all keywords are recognised.

Is there something I need to edit in my project files to get it to work correctly?

**Edit - More of an answer, copied from my comment below**
For people upgrading to VS 2015, it doesn't support MVC 4 you need to upgrade the project to MVC5. See - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Comment: A guy I work with had basically this exact error yesterday in VS11. The intellisense wouldn't see `@Html.` anything, but the code would run fine. Unfortunately I can't find his SO post at the moment to cross-link them... but I smell a VS bug...

Comment: For people upgrading to VS 2015, it doesn't support MVC 4 you need to upgrade the project to MVC5 - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the following setting to your MAIN web.config file's appSettings section:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
```

From Connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/732597/visual-studio-11-beta-razor-intellisense-not-working

Comment: That's it! Thanks! I guess my Google searches were a little too specific.

Comment: With the released version of Visual Studio (that just came out) I had to remove the webpages 1.0.0.0 entry and go back to using <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" /> in order to get IntelliSense back.

Comment: What do you know, this actually works. And I also experienced gdoten's problem and confirm his solution works.

Answer (score 5):

An update for vs2015;

Look for this element in your MAIN web.config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

and place the "newVersion" parameter in your webPages:version

ie

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

Comment: Do you got a fix for VS 2013?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that hits this page through searching, I was able to resolve this myself by following the guide on this page, line by line, until I could rebuild the project. Once I rebuilt and reloaded the project, all the intellisense came back for me.

Here is the link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2