# How to solve 'The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context' error?

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm fresher to asp.net c# environment and i'm trying to click a button which is in view and getting a pop up dialog box with two options 'Yes' and 'No'.If user click 'Yes' then need to go for a method in the controller. Here is my Javascript part.

```js
$("#btnDelete").click(function () {
                var msg = 'Confirmation Msg.';
                var div = $("<div>" + msg + "</div>");
                div.dialog({
                    title: "Confirm",
                    buttons: [
                                {
                                    text: "Yes",
                                    click: function () {
                                        var actionURL = '@Url.Action("UpdateCourse", "Course", new { }, Request.Url.Scheme)'; // Here I post my data to action method. if I select Yes in the confirm.
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",

                                        }
                                        )}
                                },
                                {
                                    text: "No",
                                    click: function () {
                                        div.dialog("close");
                                    }
                                }
                    ]
                });
            });
```

But for

```
var actionURL = '@Url.Action("UpdateCourse", "Course", new { }, Request.Url.Scheme)';
```

' it will give me an error at run time '**The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context**. There are so many questions and answers are based on this scene. But i can't exactly get idea from those materials. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514745/asp-net-mvc-url-action-in-jquery-is-not-recognized  it appears to address the problem, trying to call a Razr helper function in JavaScript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913572/model-viewbag-and-url-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-razor-mv perhaps this?

Comment: if this JS is in .cshtml file then it should be fine. but if its in .js file it wont work. Because Url is a c# class not a javascript one

Comment: You need to have a Controller class if im not mistaken..
in your case, it can be CourseController.